# BeautifulSoup first element incorrect

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Have an interesting problem.

Note: upgraded lxml and bs4 to latest version, same issue.

I am parsing english wikipedia. I have used `wikiextractor.py` to break my dump up into several xml documents, containing about 100 articles each, seperated into `<doc>` tags. Within each article are the anchor tags, which I am attempting to capture and store in a relations fields.

However, I am having a strange issue:

```
collection = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
entry = collection.find_all('doc')[0].find_all('a')
#this returns ALL anchor tags in the entire xml file
#but...
entry = collection.find_all('doc')[1].find_all('a')
#returns only the anchor tags for that specific entry.
```

The formatting of the xml is consistent (attached in gist [here](http://gist.github.com/ianseyer/e754cf3d3df34757025f295b1f264d75))

Calling `entry['title']` on element `0` returns `"The Offspring"`(correct) but calling `entry.text` on element `0` returns the entire file.

Am I missing some xml header or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the full file, if you search the xml for `<div style="float:left;">` you will see there is no closing tag which is causing the issue.

With the bad line:

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
In [3]: collection = BeautifulSoup(open("foo.xml").read(),"lxml")   
In [4]: e1 = collection.find('doc').find_all('a')    
In [5]: e2 = collection.find_all('doc')[1].find_all('a')    
In [6]: len(e1)
6411    
In [7]: len(e2)
43    
In [8]: len(collection.find_all("a"))
6411    
In [9]: len(collection.find('doc').text)
819562    
In [10]:len(collection.find_all('doc')[1].text)
3908    
In [11]: len(collection.text)
819562
```

Bad line removed:

```
In [28]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
In [29]: collection = BeautifulSoup(open("foo.xml").read(),"lxml")    
In [30]: e1 = collection.find('doc').find_all('a')    
In [31]: e2 = collection.find_all('doc')[1].find_all('a')    
In [32]: len(e1)
Out[32]: 260    
In [33]: len(e2)
Out[33]: 43    
In [34]: len(collection.find_all("a"))
Out[34]: 6411   
In [35]: len(collection.find('doc').text
Out[35]: 22882    
In [36]: len(collection.find_all('doc')[1].text)
Out[36]: 3908    
In [37]: len(collection.text)
Out[37]: 819564
```

For broken html you can use the html.parser with bs4 which is a little more forgiving:

```
In [57]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [58]: collection = BeautifulSoup(open("foo.xml").read(),"html.parser")    
In [59]: e1 = collection.find('doc').find_all('a')    
In [60]: e2 = collection.find_all('doc')[1].find_all('a')    
In [61]: (len(e1))
Out[61]: 260    
In [62]: (len(e2))
Out[62]: 43    
In [63]: (len(collection.find_all("a")))
Out[63]: 6411    
In [64]: (len(collection.find('doc').text))
Out[64]: 22881    
In [65]: (len(collection.find_all('doc')[1].text))
Out[65]: 3910   
In [66]: (len(collection.text))
Out[66]: 819582
```

Or combine both lxml and bs4 using [lxml.html.soupparser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html):

```
In [69]: from lxml.html.soupparser import parse    
In [70]: xml = parse(open("foo.xml"))    
In [71]: e3 = xml.xpath("//doc[1]//a")   
In [72]: e4 = xml.xpath("//doc[2]//a")    
In [73]: (len(e3))
Out[73]: 260    
In [74]: (len(e4))
Out[74]: 43    
In [75]: (len(xml.xpath("//a")))
Out[75]: 6411
```

Comment: Interesting. I only posted a section of the doc into the gist. Here is the full thing: would you mind checking again? https://gist.github.com/ianseyer/e754cf3d3df34757025f295b1f264d75

Comment: @ian,  the issue is actually with the xml

Comment: are you inducing that, or did you find an error in it?

Comment: @ian, look at the edit remove that line and run your code

Comment: Oh jeez. Thank you very much. Is there a way in bs4 to ignore all style tags? Or what would you recommend, given that I have hundreds and hundreds of these files?

Comment: @ian, I would probably consider it a bug relating to  `wikiextractor.py`.  I added a couple of ways that should work.

Comment: For me the answer was needed second object, so needed collection.find_all("xx"). ex: `collection.find_all("span")[2].text`